# ruby net/http difficulties

Tags: ruby, perl, net-http

I have some perl code that I'm trying to port to ruby.  The perl code does what I want to, but I'm having some difficulty getting similar results out of the ruby code which is all the more frustrating because what I'm doing isn't terribly complicated.

first, the perl code:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $cookie_jar  = HTTP::Cookies->new(file => "/home/blah/lwpcookies.txt", autosave => 0);
my $ua      = LWP::UserAgent->new('cookie_jar' => $cookie_jar);

my $p = {
    'param1'    => 'p1val',
    'param2'    => 'p2val',
    'param3'    => 'p3val',
    'param4'    => 'p4val',
    'param5'    => 'p5val',
    'param6'    => 'p6val',
     };

my $res = $ua->post('https://sitename.somesite.com/login_page.php', $p); #login
my $url = "https://sitename.sometime.com/report.php?startdate=2012-1-1&enddate=2012-1-2";
$res = $ua->get($url);
```

I can then access $res->content and get what I want out of it.

I've tried the same in ruby using net/http, but I'm not able to get the same results.  I'm also having some trouble figuring out what parts are even not working.

Here's the ruby code:

```
require 'net/http'
params  = Hash.new
params['param1']    = 'p1val'
params['param2']    = 'p2val'
params['param3']    = 'p3val'
params['param4']    = 'p4val'
params['param5']    = 'p5val'
params['param6']    = 'p6val'

uri = URI.parse('https://sitename.somesite.com/login_page.php')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.set_form_data(params)
res = http.request(request)
cookies = res.response['set-cookie']

# for what it's worth, I'm pretty sure the problem has already occurred by this point
uri = URI.parse("https://sitename.somesite.com/report.php?startdate=2012-1-1&enddate=2012-1-2")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request['Cookie'] = cookies

res = http.request(request)
```

Thoughts? Suggestions?  Tell me why I'm an idiot?  Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem? Do you get an exception or what?

Comment: in the authentication piece, res.code is 302 and res.body is blank.  I tried chasing down redirects but it seemed to bounce back and forth between two pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org), it does cookies and redirects for you:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.post url1, params
```

cookie is set now

```
response = agent.get url2
```

Comment: That made life MUCH simpler!  Thanks!